# g++ can't link curl lib files

Tags: c++, linux, curl, linker

I'm having some issues with getting g++ to link the curl lib files. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with the linux dev plugin and Ubuntu Server 17.04.

`curl-config --libs` gave an output of `-Lcurl` which I tried adding to the linker options in `Project settings > Linker > Command Line > Additional options`. I also added the `--cflags` output to the compile options. This didn't fix the issue.

Then I tried the source from the website and used make and make install. `curl-config --libs` gave me a different output of `-L/usr/local/lib -lcurl`. I changed the options in the linker and this still didn't work.

The linker output says lots of "undefined reference to " and then the curl methods. I have `#include <curl/curl.h>` in the cpp file.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a default installion you will specify the `curl` library to `gcc` with `-lcurl`, as reported by `curl-config --libs`. And to pass this on the `gcc` command line generated by VCLinux, add `curl` to the *<del>Additional</del> Library Dependencies* line under *Linker* / *Input* in the VS project properties. Note that you enter just **curl**, VCLinux supplies the `-l` and the gcc linker expands it to the actual filename of `libcurl.a` (or `libcurl.so` if you're linking a shared library).

You do not normally have to specify the library search path since `/usr/lib` etc. are automatically on the library search path. On Debian 9 for example, `libcurl.a` is in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`. But if you install curl somewhere non-standard, add the path to *Additional Library Directories* under *Linker* / *General*. If you are installing curl from your Linux distribution, remember to install the development files as well; on Debian this is the package `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` .

curl is compatible with `pkg-config` so, as an alternative to entering the paths and library names directly, you can specify `%24(pkg-config --cflags libcurl)` in *C++* / *All Options* / *Additional Options* and `%24(pkg-config --libs libcurl)` in *Linker* / *All Options* / *Additional Options*.
Note that `%24` is an encoded `$` because otherwise Visual Studio tries (and fails) to interpret the string as a macro.

Comment: Thanks alot that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because there's no h after the . in your include? Other than that, Visual Studio also needs to know the search path for your headers and libraries. It can search the build output or some of its default directories which are the VC++ directories. Beyond that you have to tell it where to search, by using some of the other menus close by.

Comment: Sorry that was a spelling mistake. fixed it now.