# Specify external library for linux from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, g++

I'm developing linux(ubuntu) c++ project from Visual Studio 2017. I want to integrate googletest into my code. I have installed googletest and run test example according [following tutorial](https://www.eriksmistad.no/getting-started-with-google-test-on-ubuntu/). Everything works fine when I run it from bash terminal using cmake.

Now I need to run it using VS. For that I need to specify path to */usr/lib/libgtest.a* from VS. I added `/usr/lib` into *Linker->General->Additional Library Directories* and added `libgtest.a` into *Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies*. But compiler still cannot link the library:

> g++: error: libgtest.a: No such file or directory

Comment: you need to change your makefile, AFAIK it can't be done using _Linker_ property tab.

Comment: It seems that I have not direct acces to makefile. Makefile generated internally in VS.

Comment: See answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570103/g-cant-link-curl-lib-files/45578921
 . Note that VCLinux uses MSBuild by default, so no makefile is involved.

Comment: Alternatively, if you prefer Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies to Linker->Input->Library Dependencies, you must specify the full path, i.e. the line will read /usr/lib/libgtest.a

Answer (score 0):

Try omit "lib" and ".a" from the file name as these portions of the filename seem to be added by the linker itself. In your case you would reference "gtest".

Answer (score 0):

Try Configuration Properties -> Linker->Input->Library Dependencies with "gtest". Note: libgtest.a must in standard location so linker can search.