# visual studio 2017 linux c++ librt

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2017

I've read, I can use Visual Studio 2017 on Windows to develop C++ application with remotely debugging on a Linux machine. I like this idea because I'm familiair with VS2017 for C# on Windows applications.

For my new study, I need to develop on Linux but for example must develope applications which use shared memory via Posix. So I need to include the LIBRT library. But this one is specific for Linux, so if I need to use such kind of specific linux library's, could I then also use this VS2017 setup?

If how, how does that work because I did not find any information about it.
Thx

Comment: Honestly, if you're programming for Linux, just program on Linux. You're trying to open yourself up to a whole world of pain.

Comment: The things you propably like are "VisualGDB" and "WinGDB". Both plugins for Visual Studio. The code gets compiled on the remote unix machine and therefore the linking is done there. No need to get LIBRT somehow in windows

Comment: I've found VisualGDB too and want to try it. A next question then is also, how does VS intellisense then work when I use methode's from the library... I shall ask the VisualGDB team

Comment: Linux development with C++ in Visual Studio is a really useful feature, especially for cross-platform development. Read about it on the Visual C++ Team Blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/11/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/

Comment: This SO question about linking `libcurl` gives additional information on linking libraries on the Linux remote thru VSLinux which can be be applied to `librt`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570103/g-cant-link-curl-lib-files/45578921#45578921

Comment: Install WSL and also Visual Studio Linux development tools, then you'll be able to develop on Linux locally.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same obstacle but for libcurl. What fixed it was adding gcc arguments in the Visual Studio linker. Right click the project and pick `Properties->Linker->All Optptions->Additional Options` and add the same parameter you would give to g++, in my case `-lcurl`. I have also tested it for `-pthread`.

[image]

Comment: you saved my day (the second, actually)!