# How to include the ncurses.h library in C++ Visual Studio Linux Project when targeting Ubuntu on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ubuntu

I am trying to create a C++ console based program that will utilize the ncurses.h library. I am using Visual Studio 2017 targeting the WSL subsystem (Ubuntu).

Within ubuntu, running on my WSL, I have installed the ncurses libraries successfully.

I have created a new Project in VS. After unsuccessfully being able to get the #include  to work correctly, I followed instructions on [Stack to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570103/g-cant-link-curl-lib-files/45578921) and added 'ncurses' in the Library Dependencies line under Linker / Input in the VS project properties. This enabled the application to compile the first time, and I was able to see in the Console Output that the library file was found and linked. However, VS still gives squiggly lines (errors) under all of the function names associated with the ncurses library. Also, the code does not work as expected, as the terminal appears to freeze. After running the code 2x, it appears now that the code will not build at all and I receive a strange error message that says the "program to debug does not exist on the remote system"

Can anyone please help? I've been using Visual Studio as my IDE with the WSL for school and would like to continue doing so. Future projects will be dependent on the ncurses library.

thank you for your help